# Why auto cannot be used to define an implicitly deleted constructor

Tags: c++, gcc

I have this small snippet (compiled with `g++`) where I have defined a move constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  A() = delete;
  A(int value) : value(value) {}
  void operator=(const auto &other) = delete;
  ~A() { cout << "Destructor called..." << endl; }

  A(const auto &other) {
    cout << "Copy constructor called..." << endl;
    value = other.value;
  }

  A(const A &&other) {
    cout << "Move constructor called..." << endl;
    value = other.value;
  }

private:
  int value;
};

int main() {
  A p1(2);
  A p2(p1);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting `main.cpp:27:10: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr A::A(const A&)'`

From what I understand, there is a compiler convention to implicitly delete any copy operations when a move constructor is defined. They will have to be explicitly defined if the user needs them.

However, I attempt to define a copy constructor using `auto` as the argument. If the constructor signature is `A(const A &other)` the program runs fine.

Since `auto` will be resolved to `A`, what is the reason for which the compiler still deems that particular constructor deleted?

Comment: Because `A(const auto &other)` cannot be a copy constructor. This is similar to why a templated constructor cannot be a copy constructor.

Comment: If you remove the move constructor, you don't see "Copy constructor called...", because `A(const auto &other)` is not a copy constructor.

Comment: "_Since auto will be resolved to A_": A "function" declaration with a placeholder (`auto`) in the parameters is not a function, but a function template. It won't resolve to just `A`. It will accept any type as argument in a construction. And as the answer says, function templates can never be copy constructors, so that there still is the implicit one that is deleted and a better match in overload resolution (because it is not a template).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since auto will be resolved to A, what is the reason for which the compiler still deems that particular constructor deleted?

Because `A::A(const auto &)` cannot be a copy constructor as when `auto` is used in the parameter of a function, that function declaration/definition is actually for a function template. Basically `A::A(const auto&)` is a templated constructor. But according to [class.copy.ctor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.ctor#1) a templated constructor cannot be a copy constructor.

> A **non-template constructor** for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]).

(emphasis mine)

---

And since you've defined a move constructor `A::A(const A&&)`, the synthesized copy ctor `A::A(const A&)` is **implicitly deleted**. But note that the implicitly deleted copy ctor `A::A(const A&)` takes part in overload resolution and is still a better match than the templated constructor `A::A(const auto&)`. Thus, the copy ctor is chosen but since it is deleted(implicitly) we get the mentioned error.

---